# layout view doesn't shown when alert text is very long

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

In options menu, there is one dedicated about the author of the App. It shows some describing text and I added a layout with a picture with two buttons one to close the dialog and another to send mail. This is the code:

```
public void autorVitals(){

    String mensaje = getString(R.string.descripcionAutor);
    //mensaje = mensaje + mensaje;
    //mensaje = mensaje + mensaje + mensaje;

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View aut_view = factory.inflate(R.layout.author, null);

        Button buttonclosedial  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botonok);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.tituloDescAut));

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setView(aut_view)
            .setMessage(mensaje);

            // create alert dialog
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            botoncerrardial.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

For tablets, this menu is seen perfectly. But I've realized that for devices with small screen, just only the mensaje's text is displayed entirely if you scroll down up to the end line but the aut_view is not seen. Reading is stackoverflow some guys set some properties to the layout like to fill parent, add scroll view etc. I've used them all with no desired result. Now, also I've realized if I make the text shorter, the layout could partially seen and also scrolled separately of the text. How can I fix this in an elegant way and good view for the user? I think the best solution is put altogether, text, picture and buttons in one layout, don't you think?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
// you put this line after alertdialog
ScrollView scrolview = new ScrollView(this);
//put this line before alertdialog.create.show()
scrolview.addview(aut_view); // so you create a scrollview as the root view, and add the inflated view..
```

so basically all your view will be put into a scrolling layout..